# tmux cannot copy to system clipboard

Tags: tmux

I want to use ctrl+w in tmux session to copy contents into system clipboard, follow some google search result, I add in `~/.tmux.config` the line:

```
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

then
`tmux source ~/.tmux.config` but with ctrl+w I can only copy highlighted text to other tmux session, not system clipboard. can someone help?

Comment: isn't xclip a graphical Program? So maybe use `export DISPLAY=:0` so you use the hosts xserver

Comment: @kai-dj I tried `export DISPLAY=:0` but not work

Comment: are you using tmux  thru a remote connection ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 yes, right, how to deal with this case?

Comment: if you are using a remote connection , you want may be to forward the display , so that you to use ssh with -X .